# How to use spring message source inside js file?

Tags: javascript, spring

I have a function in js file(exp : validateMyfile.js) that get a string parameter, this String has a value in myFile.properties and I need this value.
Now I want to get parameter value by spring message source.

How to use spring message source inside js file?

```
function validate(msg){
  -- so I  need msg value (value iside myFile.properties);

}
```

Comment: You have to interface with information that belongs to a backend service (database, filesystem, inmemory,...) either through HTTP (eg. via Rest-Endpoint) or by printing the required values into the html-view (server-side rendering).

Answer (score 1):

We normally read the message into a javascript variable in jsp file before passing it to a js function as follows

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var successmsg = "<fmt:message key='message.key'/>";

    function validate(){
      alert(successmsg);
    }  
</script>
```

Sometimes, we also pass it as a message from the `Controller` for a ajax call.

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController{

   @Value("${employee.add.success}")
   private String successMessage;
   @Value("${employee.add.failure}")
   private String failureMessage;

   @ResponseBody
   @RequestMapping("/addEmployee")
   public String addEmployee(...){
      ... 
      if(added){
        StatusObject status = new StatusObject();
        status.setCode(..);
        status.setMessage(successMessage);
      }else{
        StatusObject status = new StatusObject();
        status.setCode(..);
        status.setMessage(failureMessage);
      }
    //return status object
    }
}
```

And access it as follows

```
$.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(status){
          $("#result").text(status.message);
        }
});
```